# How use Jquery image cropping plugin in codeigniter?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

**Jquery image cropping**

I used Jquery image cropping plugins in my ci project, but here I facing problem in php file. while I load model in constructure its showing undefined error .

```
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Cropavatar extends CI_Controller {
    private $src;
    private $data;
    private $dst;
    private $type;
    private $extension;
    private $msg;



  function __construct($src, $data, $file) {
    $this -> setSrc($src);
    $this -> setData($data);
    $this -> setFile($file);
    $this -> crop($this -> src, $this -> dst, $this -> data);
    $this->load->model('file_manager_model', 'file_manager');
  }

above is my code and here showing below error
```

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: Cropavatar::$load
>
> Filename: controllers/cropavatar.php
>
> Line Number: 20

**Note:** I refer from this 
https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper/tree/master/examples/crop-avatar

Comment: share your code please

Comment: @azinkey , can you give any solutiont.

Comment: i think you should add crop.php as library instead controller

Comment: @AZinkey, ok thanks, I am trying now, then let you know.

Comment: Hello @AZinkey, now crop.php used as library but showing below error

{"state":200,"message":null,"result":"\/var\/www\/html\/critique\/assets\/images\/u\/20171006145947.png"}
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Missing argument 1 for CropAvatar::__construct(), called in /var/www/html/critique/system/core/Loader.php on line 1100 and defined

Filename: libraries/CropAvatar.php

Line Number: 10

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: src

Filename: libraries/CropAvatar.php

Line Number: 11

Answer (score 0):

Put `crop.php` in `libraries` folder,

and in your controller load library,

```
$this->load->library('crop');
```

**Ref :** https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html

and in class (`crop.php`)

**Modify From :**

```
function __construct($src, $data, $file) {
    $this -> setSrc($src);
    $this -> setData($data);
    $this -> setFile($file);
    $this -> crop($this -> src, $this -> dst, $this -> data);
}
```

**To:**

```
function __construct($args=array())
{
   if(!empty($args)){

    $params = args[0];

    $this->setSrc($params[0]);
    $this->setData($params[1]);
    $this->setFile($params[2]);

    $this->crop($this->src, $this->dst, $this->data);
   }
}
```

Looks like below :

```
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Cropavatar extends CI_Controller {


  function __construct() {

    // load library 
    // In the library loading function you can dynamically pass data as an array 
    // via the second parameter and it will be passed to your class constructor:

    $params = array('source', 'data', 'file');

    $this->load->library('crop', $params);



    $this->load->model('file_manager_model', 'file_manager');


   }
}
```

Comment: $params value not find in crop.php library file, I  print_r($params);die; but nothing showing.

Comment: as you mentioned above

Comment: function __construct($params)
    {
      print_r($params);die;
        $this->setSrc($params[0]);
        $this->setData($params[1]);
        $this->setFile($params[2]);

        $this->crop($this->src, $this->dst, $this->data);
    }

Comment: public function index() {
       $params = array('source', 'data', 'file');
       $this->load->library('cropavatar', $params);
    }

Comment: yes, I corrected that, but now showing this error

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Uninitialized string offset: 0

Filename: libraries/cropavatar.php

Line Number: 20

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Uninitialized string offset: 1

Filename: libraries/cropavatar.php

Line Number: 21

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Uninitialized string offset: 2

Filename: libraries/cropavatar.php

Line Number: 22

Comment: YES, Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => {"x":453.31760125674487,"y":207.66009835393768,"height":350.79571067550023,"width":350.79571067550023,"rotate":0}
    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => image-1465348_960_720.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/php85Ss90
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 182884
        )

)

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Uninitialized string offset: 0

Filename: libraries/cropavatar.php

Line Number: 20

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Uninitialized string offset: 1

Filename: libraries/cropavatar.php

Line Number: 21

Comment: {"state":200,"message":"Unknown upload error","result":null}Array( [0] => Array ( [0] => source [1] => data [2] => file ))

Comment: Now showing this error

 {"state":200,"message":null,"result":null}
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: exif_imagetype(s): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Filename: libraries/cropavatar.php

Line Number: 41

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Illegal string offset 'error'

Filename: libraries/cropavatar.php

Line Number: 59

Comment: @Manoranjanpanda this not related to codeigniter, its related to your  library, pass your argument properly

Comment: Hello @akshayhegde

Comment: No sir, still I am struggling for that issue, missing argument error cant solve

Comment: Now I implement like this : In controller construct using this 
    
    $params = array('source' => 'source', 'data' => 'data', 'file' => 'file');
    $this->load->library('cropavatar',$params);

and in library file using like this:

 function __construct($src = null, $data = null, $file=null) {
    $this -> setSrc($src);
    $this -> setData($data);
    $this -> setFile($file);
    $this -> crop($this -> src, $this -> dst, $this -> data);
  }

Comment: But now showing this error : 

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: exif_imagetype() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array given

Filename: libraries/Cropavatar.php

Line Number: 46

Comment: you can check in crop.php file in below link

https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper/blob/master/examples/crop-avatar/crop.php